# adding views within views in onCreateView method

Tags: android

I have a following Notification Fragment. The name of this file is notification_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notification_desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Lorem Epsum" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

*I do have another xml file which is notification.xml.*

Im using the following code to inflate the notification_fragment.xml file.

```
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_fragment, container, false);
        initView();

        return rootView;
      }

      public void initView(){
        notification_desc = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.notification_desc);
    }

}
```

what i need to do is that the values of notfication_desc will be dynamic hence number of textfield that should be displayed will increase dynamically. So i want to set values for textviews within notification_fragment.xml. Finally, I want to inflate this xml with notification.xml dynamically each time when values for notification_desc are set. How can I do this? or simply How can I be able to create a subview within onCreateView method?

**UPDATE**

Im retrieving values from sqlite db and trying to  display the values dynamically.

This is how I retrieve the values,

```
List<PendingOrdersDao> contacts = db.getAllPendingOrders();

for (PendingOrdersDao cn : contacts) {
        initView(cn.getProformoInvoiceNumber(), cn.getProformoInvoiceDate());
}
```

When I invoke initView method, it should add views to the layout dynamically depending on the number of entries present in db. Following is my initView method.

```
private void initView(String proformaInvoice, String invoiceDate){

        LinearLayout mLinearLayoutContainer = (LinearLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.dashboard_container);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_fragment, mLinearLayoutContainer, false);

        mProformaInvoice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dashProformaInvoiceNo);
        mInvoiceNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dashInvoiceNo);

        mProformaInvoice.setText(proformaInvoice);
        mInvoiceNumber.setText(invoiceNumber);

        mLinearLayoutContainer.addView(v);
    }
```

The problem is that, there are three entries in the db hence  3views should be displayed but it displays only one view

Comment: please have a look at my answer. If you have any doubt please do let me know

Answer (score 0):

I'm very new to Android development, so this may or may not be at all correct.

Couldn't you call .setText("whatever you want") on the TextView during the OnVisible() call of your Activity or something along those lines?

```
TextView notificationDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notification_desc);

notificationDescription.setText("Put yo text here!");
```

Comment: I can! but what i want is that i have to add sub views within onCreateView method

Answer (score 0):

What I can see is you want to add sub views dynamically to your LinearLayout. You just need a [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) ,any ViewGroup, (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, FrameLayout, ...) and use [addView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View%29) method to add children to it.

```
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_fragment, container, false);
    initView();
    return rootView;
}

public void initView(){
    mLinearLayoutContainer = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_id);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    // The below code can be inside a loop or whatever you want
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification, mLinearLayoutContainer, false);
    mLinearLayoutContainer.addView(v);
}
```

Comment: will you please elaborate?

Comment: I will give you an example.

Comment: Thank you. But it doesnt add view to an existing view. Only the view at the top appears. Rest of the views are not appearing.

Comment: Im fetching values from database and  invoking initView as initView(cn.getProformoInvoiceNumber(),cn.getProformoInvoiceDate()). It adds only one view but it should add three views since there are three rows in db

Comment: You had put initView inside the loop and that's wrong. You should inflate the view once, and inflate child views after that and add them one by one.

Comment: where should i put the initView()?

Comment: currently im invoking initView within for loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104718/discussion-between-ahmed-hegazy-and-stanly).

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand you want to add textview dynamically to your layout. In order to do this consider Linearlayout of your xml file as parent layout in which you have to add textViews dynamically. And use the below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:id="@+id/root_ll"
android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

LinearLayout rootLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_ll);


 private void createDynamicLayout() {
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);

        TextView fieldLabel = new TextView(mContext);
                    fieldLabel.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textViewSize);
                    fieldLabel.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.activity_tv_text_color));
                    fieldLabel.setText("your text");
                    fieldLabel.setLayoutParams(params1);
                    rootLayout.addView(fieldLabel);
 }
```